# How to dynamically create MongoTemplate instances, with credentials?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

Prior to Spring Data MongoDB 1.9.0-RELEASE, I was able to create a MongoTemplate object as follows:
`new MongoTemplate(client, dbName, credentials)`.  Upon upgrading, this constructor no longer works, giving an error to use `MongoCredential` instead.  However, there is no similar `MongoTemplate` constructor that uses `MongoCredential`.  It appears that the only way to specify credentials now is when constructing the `MongoClient` object.

However, since my app is multitenant on the database level, this doesn't work because it does not allow for additional credentials to be added after construction (meaning `MongoTemplate`s cannot be created dynamically).  It also is not ideal because if any of the credentials in the list are bad, none of the database connections work, as opposed to just the one with bad credentials.

I also do not want to create a new `MongoClient` instance for each database.  From what I understand, doing so would create a new connection for each database rather than letting `MongoClient` manage a connection pool, which is ultimately not sustainable since Mongo only allows a finite number of connections.

Do I have any options here besides continuing to use the outdated library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is creating a single user in the `admin` database that has access to all of the databases that I need (achieved via the `roles` array).  I create one `MongoClient`, authorizing as that user against the `admin` database.  Then I am able to create `MongoTemplate` objects dynamically without issue, because the user I'm authorized as has`readWrite` permissions on those databases.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is instantiate the `MongoClient` and cache it using a `HashMap` with some unique db identifier as key and mongoClient as value. Use that create `MongoTemplate`

Comment: That's ultimately still creating a `MongoClient` object per database, right?  I don't think that's great, for the reasons I explain in the third paragraph, though I haven't done testing to verify my assumptions there are correct.

Comment: This line is from the javadoc of MongoClient.java "A MongoDB client with internal connection pooling. For most applications, you should have one MongoClient instance for the entire JVM." In your case each MongoClient instance will point to a specific DB to achieve multi-tenancy we don't have to do much about managing connections ourselves. Please try it out and publish the results.

Comment: "A MongoDB client with internal connection pooling. For most applications, you should have one MongoClient instance for the entire JVM."

This seems to confirm my suspicion that instantiating multiple `MongoClient`s is not good practice.

Comment: Most applications are not multi-tenant. Most Applications deal with single database usually.

Comment: I tested my theory, and it does appear that using the `MongoClient` per database approach creates one connection per database, and these connections are not garbage collected.

Comment: if you don't mind can you brief about your multi-tenant setup?

Comment: There is one database per tenant, accessed via the `MongoTemplate` class provided by Spring Data, which is used to perform database actions.  Currently, I am able to instantiate a single `MongoClient` instance (without providing credentials) and then create a `MongoTemplate` for each database (providing the credentials).  The new version of Mongo deprecates the way I'm creating the `MongoTemplate`s, with credentials.  I'm in a similar boat to the OP [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/D7QzvUuHMMk/discussion).